# Vuex store getter empty

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm following the sample code in the Vuex guide and I'm getting a weird result (at least for me).

**Vuex Store**

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    name: ""
  },

  mutations: {
    updateName(state, newName) {
      state.name = newName;
    }
  },

  getters: {
    getName: state => state.name
  }
});

export default store;
```

**Component**, inside the `<script>` tags:

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Home",

  data: function() {
    return {
      showingName: true
    };
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getName"])
  },

  methods: {
    getNameHandler() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log(this.$store.getters.getname); // returns undefined
    }
  }
};
```

Here is a live sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/yww774xrmj

Basically the question is, why the `console.log` returns undedined?. you can see that by clicking the button in the **Home** component. I'm following the same pattern as shown in the official Vuex guide:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access

Unless I'm missing an import or a `Vue.use()`, but what gets my attention is that using the ´mapGetters´ actually allows me to use the getter as a computed property. You can change the name property of the state with the button in the **About** component.

Comment: It's a typo. Your getter is `getName` but you're trying to log `getname`

Comment: Ohh... this is effing embarrassing :|, One tends to think that after some time you don't do this kind of mistakes... Thanks @Phil !!

Comment: Ahaha, I feel you tend to do them more ;-). I wish all questions on SO were this detailed though

Comment: I moderate in the GreenSock forums, so I know the pain of non-concrete and succinct questions

Answer (score 0):

The getter name is case-sensitive.

```
this.$store.getters.getName
```

You have

```
this.$store.getters.getname
```

Comment: Did this **really** need an answer? There's a _"close as typo"_ vote option for which this already has two votes

Answer (score 0):

First of all install the chrome plugin for vuex [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en).

Please check your mutations -> updateName is updating the state or not then you will get you're value from getters -> getName.

I hope that gonna help you out.

Thanks.